# Why I get warning 'Encountered two children with the same key, `1`.' even when there are only one element in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of comments I want to print out. But every time I keep getting this warning: *"Encountered two children with the same key, '1'."* even when there are only one comment in array.

How can I fix that?

```
let content = props.comments.map((comment) =>
        <Card key={props.product.id}  className="shadow" body>
            <p">{comment}</p>
        </Card>
    )
```

Comment: Show us the props.comments array

Comment: The key should be the id of the comment (if there is one), not the product. Something like `key={comment.id}`.

Comment: I personally use the `uuid` package (`npm i uuid`) for applying keys. Import the package as `import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";` and then replace the key: `<Card key={uuid()}  className="shadow" body>`.

Comment: @srWebDev So you create a new uuid on every render, and the `key` prop becomes useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that map method takes (currentValue, index, arr). If props.product.id not working then use current index of item instead of a props.product.id

```
let content = props.comments.map((comment, index) =>
    <Card key={index}  className="shadow" body>
        <p">{comment}</p>
    </Card>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is:

```
let content = props.comments.map((comment, i) =>
        <Card key={i}  className="shadow" body>
            <p">{comment}</p>
        </Card>
    )
```

Comment: React documentation warns against using the `map` index as a key.